# Styles are not applied

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following triggers in a custom button style:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
</Trigger>
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFF9800" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFF9800" />
</Trigger>
```

But they don't apply in my GUI at all. Below is the entire Style.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="Button.Hoverless" TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}">
                    <Border Name="border"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="False" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF9800" />
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0.50" />
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFB850" />
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="False" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelected" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFF9800" />
                        </MultiTrigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFF9800" />
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFFF9800" />
                        </Trigger>

                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.95" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

I'm new to WPF styling and thus I'm not sure where I went wrong with this. Also included is the button code:

```
<Button x:Name="btnScanFP1" Content="Scan Fingerprint" Grid.Column="1" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Top"
        Width="227" Height="21" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" FontSize="11" Click="btnScanFP1_Click"
        Background="{x:Null}" BorderBrush="#FFFF9800" Foreground="#FFFF9800"
        Style="{StaticResource Button.Hoverless}"/>
```

Comment: You have defined the key as `Button.Hoverless` which is of type of DottedXamlName. This type of specification  is used for property and event qualified references, and also for attached members. So remove the . from your key name.

Comment: Also, the resource created in windows.Resources is a keyed resource so it will apply automatically. So where ever you require this style you should define it as `Style="{StaticResource ResourceKeyName}"`. If you want to apply to all buttons then remove the key attribute.

Comment: You're explicitly setting the background on your button to `#FFFF9800`, which has a [higher priority](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#listing) than the setters in your style's triggers. Using `Buttonbase` as `TargetType` is perhaps a bit odd but shouldn't be a problem, as `Button` inherits from `ButtonBase`.

Comment: @PieterWitvoet You're right. That did solve it. Would you like to make it an answer? I just had to remove the properties from the button itself.

Comment: See my edit for another solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms743230%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#listing), explicitly setting a property has a higher priority than a style trigger (which itself has a higher priority than a style setter).

Removing `BorderBrush="#FFFF9800"` from your button will allow the style triggers to alter the border brush as expected. The same goes for the `Foreground` property.

But perhaps a better solution is to refer to the border in your control template by name:

```
<Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FFFFFFFF" />
</Trigger>
```

This overrides the template-binding on the border's `BorderBrush` property, so it will apply even when you explicitly set the `BorderBrush` property on your button.